# How can I make a bottom bar with a fab button in the center of the bottom bar in kotlin compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomsheetdialog, android-bottomappbar

I'm currently making a bottom bar, I think I've done everything right but it's not working properly. the background is completely black and the fab button appears in the center of the screen and the other buttons are not visible. What could be the problem here? Have you ever faced such a problem? Can you help me ?

I want to do like this -> https://www.mobiler.dev/post/jetpack-compose-ile-bottom-navigation-tasarlamak

hear is my code :

**BottomNavItemProvider.kt**

```
class BottomNavItemProvider private constructor() {

  

      companion object {
            fun provideBottomNavItemList() = listOf(
                BottomNavItem(Screen.SignUpStartScreen.route, "Home", Icons.Outlined.Home),
                BottomNavItem(Screen.SignUpFinishScreen.route, "Chat", Icons.Outlined.Notifications)
            )
        }
    }
```

**FancyBottomNavigation.kt**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun FancyBottomNavigation(
    navController: NavController,
    bottomNavItemList: List<BottomNavItem>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bottomNavBackgroundColor: Color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.Black else Color.White,
    bottomNavItemColor: Color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color.White else Color.Black,
    clicks: Pair<(BottomNavItem) -> Unit, () -> Unit>
) {

    val backStackEntry = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentRoute = backStackEntry.value?.destination?.route

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalRippleTheme provides NoRippleTheme) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
        ) {

            BottomNavigation(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                backgroundColor = bottomNavBackgroundColor,
                elevation = 5.dp
            ) {
                bottomNavItemList.forEach { item ->

                    val isItemSelected = item.route == currentRoute

                    FancyBottomNavigationItem(
                        selectedItem = item,
                        isItemSelected = isItemSelected,
                        selectedItemColor = DefaultDYTColor,
                        unSelectedItemColor = bottomNavItemColor,
                        navItemOnClick = clicks.first
                    )
                }
            }
            FancyCenterItem()
        }
    }
}
```

**FancyBottomNavigationItem.kt**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun RowScope.FancyBottomNavigationItem(
    selectedItem: BottomNavItem,
    isItemSelected: Boolean,
    selectedItemColor: Color,
    unSelectedItemColor: Color,
    navItemOnClick: (BottomNavItem) -> Unit,
) {

    BottomNavigationItem(
        selected = isItemSelected,
        onClick = { navItemOnClick(selectedItem) },
        selectedContentColor = selectedItemColor,
        unselectedContentColor = unSelectedItemColor,
        icon = {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(SMALL_GAP),
                modifier = if (isItemSelected) Modifier
                    .background(Color.Transparent.copy(alpha = 0.05f), shape = CircleShape)
                    .padding(MEDIUM_PADDING) else Modifier
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = selectedItem.icon,
                    contentDescription = selectedItem.title
                )
                AnimatedVisibility(visible = isItemSelected) {
                    Text(
                        text = selectedItem.title,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

**FancyCenterItem.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun FancyCenterItem() {

    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState =
        BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )

    // Declaring Coroutine scope
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // Creating a Bottom Sheet
    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp)
                    .background(Color(0XFF0F9D58))) {
                Column(
                    Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hello Geek!", fontSize = 20.sp, color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        },
        sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp
    ) {}

    Column(
        Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
       Image(
           painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_bottom_bar_fab),
           contentDescription ="fab",
           modifier = Modifier.clickable {
               coroutineScope.launch {
                   if (bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.isCollapsed){
                       bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
                   }else{
                       bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                   }
               }
           })
    }
}
```

**Ripple.kt**

```
object NoRippleTheme : RippleTheme {

    @Composable
    override fun defaultColor() = Color.Unspecified

    @Composable
    override fun rippleAlpha(): RippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
}
```

**DashBoard.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashBoard(navController: NavController) {

    val bottomNavItemList = provideBottomNavItemList()

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            FancyBottomNavigation(
                navController = navController,
                bottomNavItemList = bottomNavItemList,
                modifier = Modifier,
                clicks = Pair(
                    first = { bottomNavItem ->
                        navController.navigate(bottomNavItem.route)
                    },
                    second = {
                        Log.i("MainActivity", "Center Item Clicked!")
                    }
                )
            )
        }) {

    }

    Text(text = "DASHBOARD")

}
```

When I want to show it in dashBoard.kt for trial purposes, the screenshot looks like this

Let me explain briefly what I want to do. In the bottom bar, there will be items like the link I shared, for example home, setting etc. I want a fab (floating action button) in the middle of these items. If the user clicks fab, the bottom sheet will open. In the screenshot I shared right now, the blue + button in the center is my floating action button (fab), when it is clicked, a bottom sheet opens from the bottom up, but it looks very bad and does not work properly. I hope I explained my problem properly.

[image]

Comment: is this what you trying to achieve : [M2 Bottom App Bar](https://m2.material.io/components/app-bars-bottom)

Comment: yes something like that but when I click fab bottomsheet open. is the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

The [bottom navigation bar design](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/_wVZOGd-J2P8egccQlY_MI6w01npq0bfNY1zVlvWjYqPFFjLP8G0ZNcCEkB572LMGT-GkptT_rVZRgj4jSn7ibRN02pMhCIG4Qjy4A=w1064-v0) you said was introduced under Material2.
check out [M2 BottomBar Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#BottomAppBar(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Function1)) Reference for implementation in Jetpack Compose

the approach you took to implement FAB is wrong. Instead of creating a clickable Image you should do something like this in your FancyCenterItem function:

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = {//control bottomSheet},
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.SomeIcon
        )
    }
```